# Android - Detectar palavra específica em um EditText

Tags: java, android, edittext

Como faço para que quando um botão for pressionado, ative uma função apenas se uma palavra específica tiver sido digitado em qualquer posição em um EditText? Obrigado.

main.xml:

```
<EditText
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:hint="Digite aqui..."
android:id="@+id/searchfield"/>

<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:text="Botão"
android:id="@+id/btn"/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
final EditText search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchfield);


go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View p1){
//O que devo colocar na condição if?
if(search.getText().toString()){
function();
}

}
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o método [contains()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) da classe String:

```
if(search.getText().toString().contains("palavra")){
    //entra aqui se a *palavra* estiver no texto
}
else{
    //entra aqui se a *palavra* NÃO estiver no texto
}
```